# How to get multiple maximum values from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like:

```
example = {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':1}
```

I want to keep only the maximum values and keys. The output should be:

```
{'a':2, 'b':2}
```

This is different from just getting the maximum value, as has been asked in other places. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: sorry not stuck, upvoted the most liked answer but didn't press accept yet. My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do this:

```
{k:v for k,v in example.items() if v == max(example.values())}

>>>

{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with `pandas` I suggest the following:

```py
s = pd.Series(example)
s[s == s.max()].to_dict()

>>> {'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
example = {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':1}
filtered = {k:v for k,v in example.items() if v == max(example.values())}
print(filtered)
```

output

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```